# jsTree sort function recycling

Tags: javascript, sorting, jstree

I have multiple *jstrees* on my hands. For each I added the `sort` plugin and configured:

```
  "core": { .. },
  "plugins": ['sort', ..],
  "sort": action_sort,
  ...
```

I then proceeded to write the following problematic function:

```js
/** @param id_node{1,2}: Despite of what can be read here: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.sort
 *   this function will receive 2 strings with the _id_s of the nodes to be sorted, not the nodes themselves.
 * @return 1 or -1. Will cause the nodes to be sorted alphanumerically using String.localeCompare(..). */
function action_sort(id_node1, id_node2)
{
    let node1 = $('#navtree').jstree(true).get_node(id_node1);
    let node2 = $('#navtree').jstree(true).get_node(id_node2);
    let code = node1.text.localeCompare(node2.text);
    return (code >= 0) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

The problem being that hard-coded string `#navtree` that obviously will only work for the very tree with this very id.

Now, in the [documentation](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=sort) they state that the sorting function *is executed in the tree's context*. So I proceeded to experiment with `$(this)` obtaining a convoluted very large internal data structure on the growing tree.

Further experimentations attempted to find the first parent of `$('#'+id_node1)` holding the `role='tree'` attribute. However, at the time of sorting the node is still unobtainable this way.

Of course I might monkey around with currying or autogenerating custom sort functions for each tree.

But the real question is: **Is there a simpler way for my `action_sort(id_node1, id_node2)` function to know the tree it is running in, exploiting that it is run in "the tree's context"? Or more to the point: To get a handle from which I might call `.get_node(node_id)`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the default sort handler `$.jstree.defaults.sort` function, you would see that it uses a `get_text` function in the function's context. You could use this function in you code for any jsTree instance

```
function (id_node1, id_node2) {
    return this.get_text(id_node1).localeCompare(this.get_text(id_node2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This would be great and potentially unlock many more possibilities. Will check this on Monday and accept your answer then.